$e^{x+y}$ is transcendent over $\mathbb{C}(e^{x-y})$.
Prove that $e^{x+y}$ is transcendent over $\mathbb{C}(e^{x-y})$.
Ideas:
I can use the following results:
(1) If $\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{n}$ are different complex numbers, then $e^{\alpha_{1}x}, \dots , e^{\alpha_{n}x}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$.
(2) If $\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{n}$ are different algebraic numbers, then $e^{\alpha_{1}}, \dots , e^{\alpha_{n}}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.
(3) $e^{x+y}$ is transcendent over $\mathbb{C}(e^{x-y})$ if and only if there exist a polynomial $f(s,t) \in \mathbb{C}[s,t]-\{0\}$ such that $f(e^{x+y},e^{x-y}) = 0$.
(4) If $f(s,t) \in \mathbb{C}[s,t]$ satisfies that $f(e^{x+y},e^{x-y}) = 0$ and $f(s,t) = \sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}s^{i}t^{j}$, then $f(e^{x+y},e^{x-y}) = \sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}e^{(i+j)x+(i-j)y}=0$.

Using the comment of Amateur_Algebraist: suppose $e^u$ is algebraic over $e^v$. Then there exists a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{C}[X,Y]\setminus 0$ such that $f(e^u,e^v)=0$. Hence $f(e^\alpha,e^\beta)=0$ for every choice of $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$, contradicting (2).
2nd attempt: the monomials of $f(e^u,e^v)$ look like $c_{k,l}e^{ku+lv}$, $c_{k,l}\in\mathbb{C}$. Choose some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and substitute $v$ by $\alpha u$. Then
$
e^{ku+lv}=e^{(k+l\alpha )u}.
$
The equation $k+l\alpha=k^\prime+l^\prime\alpha$ by assumption about $\alpha$ leads to $l=l^\prime$ and hence $k=k^\prime$. Consequently the relation $f(e^u,e^{\alpha u})=0$ leads to a non-trivial linear combination of the functions $e^{(k+l\alpha )u}$, $k+l\leq\deg(f)$, contradicting (1).

I'm not sure why Hagen Knaf's answer (+1) hasn't been accepted, so adding the following, just in case. Relying on the fact that the transcendence degree of a finitely generated field extension is well defined (hopefully covered in the OP's textbook).

The ring homomorphism $f:\Bbb{C}[u,v]\to\Bbb{C}[e^x,e^y]$ defined by $u\mapsto e^x$, $v\mapsto e^y$ is an isomorphism because it is obviously onto, and almost as obviously injective.
Therefore the fields of quotients $\Bbb{C}(u,v)$, $L:=\Bbb{C}(e^x,e^y)$ are isomorphic extensions of $\Bbb{C}$, and thus both have transcendence degree two over $\Bbb{C}$.
The field $K=\Bbb{C}(e^{x+y},e^{x-y})\subseteq L$, and the extension $L/K$ is algebraic, so the field $K$ also has transcendence degree two over $\Bbb{C}$.
On the other hand the field $M=\Bbb{C}(e^{x-y})$ has transcendence degree one over $\Bbb{C}$ because it is a simple extension.
Therefore $e^{x+y}$ is transcendental over $M$.

